# Create new column in SQL Server view with a default value

Tags: sql-server, view, unions

I have this query for a view:

```
SELECT t1.Connected, t1.Region, t1.Homespassed 
FROM connected as t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT t2.Connected, t2.Region, t2.Homespassed 
FROM connected as t2
```

I want to add a new column with a default year value. The table should like this:

```
Connected | Region | Homespassed | Year
```

Each view that we are unionizing has a different year. Please assist

Comment: Is the default year value retrieved from somewhere or is it a constant value?

Comment: no. i will assign the values to the column but its only one year for each view

Comment: @OtshepengDitshego, your view example has the same FROM source. Is it actually different for each query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok as per your comment, you have a constant value as your year so this will do the trick:

```
SELECT t1.Connected, t1.Region, t1.Homespassed, '2017' as Year FROM connected as t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT t2.Connected, t2.Region, t2.Homespassed, '2018' as Year FROM connected as t2;
```

Or if you want your code to be somewhat better:

```
DECLARE @YEAR1 CHAR(4), @YEAR2 CHAR(4);
SET @YEAR1 = '2017';
SET @YEAR2 = '2018';

SELECT t1.Connected, t1.Region, t1.Homespassed, @YEAR1 as Year FROM connected as t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT t2.Connected, t2.Region, t2.Homespassed, @YEAR2 as Year FROM connected as t2;
```

Comment: A **year** really is a **numeric** value - why do you make it a `CHAR(4)` ?? Doesn't make any sense to me ...

Comment: Since the range is 1753 to 9999 and I cannot think of any computations to be had in a constant year value, i thought that a char(4) should also provide a validation.